# Importing csv data into custom attribute in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, custom-attributes

I have a `.csv` file that I am using to modify custom attributes on users in Active Directory, but PowerShell does not like the script:

```
Import-Csv -path c:\users\user\desktop\doc.csv | ForEach-Object  { 
            Set-ADUser $_.mail -replace @{
                ExtensionAttribute1 = $_.ExtensionAttribute1
            }
        }
```

I get the following error:

> Set-ADUser : replace
>
> At line:2 char:4
>
> - Set-ADUser $_.mail -replace @{
> - CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (user123:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId: ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

The CSV only has 2 columns:

```
extensionAttribute1,mail
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Remove the space between `@` and the opening bracket `{`

Comment: That's not even a valid syntax for `Set-ADUser`, nor is it valid to have the pipe (`|`) in a new line. also, you need have the opening brace for `Foreach-Object` in the same line unless you you use a continuation/escape mark: the back tick: \`.There's no `-Replace` parameter, and if you're referring to the operator, it's still invalid syntax for that as well. What are your intentions? What is the expected result?

Comment: @Theo the way the code pasted added a space. the original code is @{ sorry for the confusion

Comment: I am trying to have the extensionAttribute1 be added to the users in AD based on their mail attribute

Comment: @Santiago, my fault! Had to confirm before I commented it lol but, now double checking, I see `-Replace` is a parameter. Thank you!:)

Answer (score 3):

The `-Identity` parameter for Set-ADUser does not take an email address.
It needs either the `DistinguishedName`, `objectGUID`, `SID` or `SamAccountName`. You can also pipe a user object directly to the cmdlet.

Because of that, you need to first try to find the user with `Get-ADUser` and if that succeeds set the attribute.

```
Import-Csv -Path 'c:\users\user\desktop\doc.csv' | ForEach-Object { 
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_.mail)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        $user | Set-ADUser -Replace @{ extensionAttribute1 = $_.extensionAttribute1 }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "No user with email address '$($_.mail)' found.."
    }
}
```

PS. I always use the exact LDAP name inside the Hash for the key name when using `-Add`, `-Replace` etc. Case sensitive.

Comment: @Theo This script adjust worked for me. thank you!